# Is it possible to use Asp.net Identity with autoincremental key fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am use my own EF database using `long` as the `Id` field. I have created all the entities and the relevant custom stores.

However when registering a new user, it is trying to call `SetPasswordHashAsync` before it has called `CreateAsync`, which means that it is trying to write to a database record that doesn't exist yet and of course it is throwing an error.

It looks like the system is expecting to know the `Id` field before it has been written to the DB but until then it cannot know the Id as it is set to be an auto-incremental field.

What am I missing? Is this even possible?

Here is the code from the AccountController (taken from the MVC project template)

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new User { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                // We do not want the user to be logged in as soon as they register. We want them have to go through the login process.
                //await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                // Send an email with this link
                string code = await userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                await userManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return View("DisplayEmail");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

and here is the code from UserManager (from Identity.core) that is called

```
    public virtual async Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(TUser user, string password)
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        var passwordStore = GetPasswordStore();
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
        }
        if (password == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
        }
        var result = await UpdatePasswordInternal(passwordStore, user, password).WithCurrentCulture();
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return result;
        }
        return await CreateAsync(user).WithCurrentCulture();
    }
```

So you can see that updating the password before calling createUser is the intended process, but how is that meant to work? That just seems wrong to me.

Comment: You'll need to show code that creates users. By default `Id` field is auto-generated, so I'm not sure why you have `SetPasswordHashAsync` before ``CreateAsync`

Comment: @trailmax What code do you want to see? 90% of the code is coming from the Identity.core assembly and hence I did not write. I have now included the code for CreateUser from UserManager.

Comment: That's a good question. I actually never before paid a close attention to this bit. Though a lot of my projects use `CreateAsync(user, password)` method with no issues.

Comment: If you follow through the code of `CreateAsync` and look through `UpdatePasswordInternal` method, it does not actually writes to DB anywhere, all it does is sets password hash and security stamp-guid on the class object - everything is in memory at this point. And ID is not required for any of these operations.

Comment: UpdatePasswordInternal calls SetPasswordHashAsync which I had assumed is meant to be a method that writes the PassHash to the DB. Is this not the case? Is SetPasswordHashAsync just meant to update the user that is passed in? Is that the case for all store methods called Setxxx? If so what store methods are actually meant to touch the DB?

Comment: `SetPasswordHashAsync` only updates class instance, does not write to DB. Yes, the name is misleading. I can't really know if there is a convention for `Setxxx` methods and which ones touch DB. Best bet would be to follow the code in a decompiler - that will be the most reliable source. All I can say that method `CreateAsync` does not do anything silly like trying to update password for non-existing DB-record.

Comment: Thanks for that, very helpful. I looked in the MySQL example and copied what their UserStore was doing, however even that wasn't enough as it was still trying to call SetLockoutEnabledAsync which according to the MySQl example writes to the DB! Changed that and it now seems to work. However something is still calling FindByNameAsync before the record has been created, but I cannot figure out what is making that call. Any ideas?

Comment: Figured out what was making that call to FindByNameAsync, it was making sure that the name didn't already exist in the DB! Which is a good thing.

Comment: Great! glad you sorted it out!